# Efficient to search for a list of terms in a document

Tags: python, algorithm, search, nlp, string-matching

I have a list of thousands of synonyms.  I also have tens of thousands of documents that I want to search for these terms.  Using python (or pseudocode) what is an efficient way of doing this?

```
# this would work for single word synonyms, but there are multiple word synonyms too
synonymSet = set([...])
wordsInDocument = set([...])
synonymsInDocument = synonymSet.intersection(wordsInDocument)

# this would work, but sounds slow
matches = []
for document in documents:
    for synonym in synonymSet:
        if synonym in document:
            matches.append(synonym)
```

Is there a good solution to this problem, or will it just take a while?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Are the multi-word synonyms all two words?  What is the upper limit of the number of words in a synonym?

Comment: there is no upper limit on the number of words.  they are unlikely larger than 10 words.

Answer (score 0):

How about building a regular expression from your list of synonyms:

```
import re

pattern = "|".join(synonymList)
regex = re.compile(pattern)

matches = regex.findall(document) # get a list of the matched synonyms
matchedSynonyms = set(matches)    # eliminate duplicates using a set
```